# my click event doesnt work after iteration

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

my problem is with click event. here is my html code
i deleted some of the stylings so it probabaly wouldnt work corectly if you copy and paste it

```
<div class="text-start parent"
                    
                    <div class="bg-info add">
                        <div class="pt-4 ps-4">
                          
                            <input type="text" class="d-inline">
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="pb-2 child"
                             
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin-right: 60px">
                            <button @click="add($event)" class="btn btn-danger"
                                    style="width: 35px; height: 35px; margin-top: -25px; "></button>
                            <span style="width: 20px;
                                          height: 1px;
                                          border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                                          position: absolute"></span>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div style="margin-right: 20px">
                            <button @click="secAdd($event)" class="btn btn-primary"
                                    style="width: 35px; height: 35px; margin-bottom: -20px"></button>
                            <span style="width: 20px;
                        height: 1px;
                        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                        position: absolute; margin-top: 23px; "></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

its like a tree digram. with each click an input and a button adds in the dom. basically, when I click the buttons it injects some HTML code into a div. my problem is in the second iteration the click event won't work

here is the vue.js code

````
        data() {
            return {
                count: 1,
                component: `<div class="bg-info add">
                        <div class="pt-4 ps-4">
                                <span class=""><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16"
                                                    fill="currentColor"
                                                    class="bi bi-x" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                  <path d="M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/>
                </svg></span>
                            <input type="text" class="d-inline">
                            <span style="width: 25px;
                                                height: 15px;
                                                border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                                                position: absolute;"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pb-2 child"
                             style="margin-right: 40px; border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.45);min-height: 40px">
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin-right: 60px">
                            <button @click="add($event)" class="btn btn-danger"
                                    style="width: 35px; height: 35px; margin-top: -25px; "></button>
                            <span style="width: 20px;
                                          height: 1px;
                                          border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                                          position: absolute"></span>
                        </div>

                    </div>`,

            }
        },
        methods: {
            add(event) {
                $(event.target).closest('.add').children('.child').append(this.component)
            },
            secAdd(event) {
                $(event.target).closest('.parent').children('.add').append(this.component)

            },

        },
    }) ```
````

Comment: You're using jquery to inject HTML - vue won't "compile" that HTML at run time, so the `@click` in the "injected" HTML has absolutely no effect - in general, if you're using jquery with vuejs, you're doing it wrong - but even if you converted this code to native DOM methods, it still won't work, because that's not how vue.js works at all